# htaccess rewrite url to css on WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I want to rewrite url to css-files(looks like http://localhost/wordpress/my-page/assets/css/style.min.css) to new path (http://localhost/wordpress/my-page/my-project/app/assets/css/style.min.css). How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code in .htacess file.

```
RewriteRule ^/wordpress/my-page/assets/css/style.min\\.css$ http://localhost/wordpress/my-page/my-project/app/assets/css/style.min.css [L]
```